# Question concerning predicate Logic

Tags: predicate-logic

how do I say in predicate logic:
$\forall x > 2 $ there exists ...

Thanks for every help!

Comment: $\forall x:( x>2 \Rightarrow \exists ...)$

Comment: doesn't that say that for all x the condition: x > 2 is true?

Comment: It says for all $x$ *if* $x>2$ is true *then* there exists ...

Comment: ok, but I think it has to be an ordinary arrow (→ instead of ⇒), am I right? At least this is how it got introduced to me...

Comment: Could tell me what is the defference between these arrows ? anyway  I meant Implication

Comment: I think →  is used when dealing with logical formulas and ⇒ for propositions, but that might also be a distinction that varies from institution to institution, meaning that they might also be used interchangeably... anyway, thanks

Comment: @Physor, this post is about these arrows https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808485/do-i-understand-the-difference-between-implies-and-to.

Comment: thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Given $P(x, y)$ is a predicate over $\mathbb{U} \times \mathbb{V}$, we have
$$(\forall x \in \mathbb{U})(\exists y \in \mathbb{V})(P(x, y)) $$

For this question, you would have something like
$$(\forall x > 2)(\exists y \in \mathbb{R})(P(x, y)) $$
Assuming $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$

We can read it as for all $x>2$ there exists some $y$ that $P(x, y)$ is a predicate, therefore, $(\forall x > 2)(\exists y \in \mathbb{R})(P(x, y)) $ is a preposition.

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ is some property and I want to write "For all $x>2$ there exists $y$ satisfying $P$" formally in first-order predicate logic, then I can write $\forall x(x>2\rightarrow \exists yP)$. There are other abbreviations for this that are usually well understood, such as $(\forall x>2) (\exists y) P$, etc.

But I wanted to add a supplementary answer based on the discussion of $\rightarrow$ vs $\Rightarrow$.

I can't say for sure, but your confusion about these two symbols might be due to the habit some people have in writing proofs, where they write $A\Rightarrow B$ to denote "I know $A$, and now I'm concluding $B$." For example I might give my students the following exercise.

> Suppose $x$ and $y$ are odd integers. Prove that $x+y$ is even.

Now, due to a mixture of laziness and over-excitement with using math symbols for the first time, many students will write a proof like this:

> $x$ and $y$ are odd integers 
> $\Rightarrow$ $x=2a+1$ and $y=2b+1$ for some integers $a,b$
> $\Rightarrow$ $x+y=2(a+b+1)$ 
> $\Rightarrow$ $x+y$ is even

So, in each line, $A\Rightarrow B$ is signifying "$A$ is true. And from this I'm now concluding $B$."

Moreover, sometimes profs will use something like this notation when lecturing on the board (usually to save time writing out too many words).

But, in any case, this use of $\Rightarrow$ is only a *convention*. By itself, $A\Rightarrow B$ means "$A$ implies $B$", which is to say "If $A$ is true then $B$ is true." One should not assume that $\Rightarrow$ is signifying anything more than just this, without double-checking the surrounding context.